# How to start with android in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am beginner.
Need help from where to start?
If you can provide some resource or tutorial then it will
very helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from [here](http://developer.android.com/index.html)
A tutorial from Lynda for beginner it very simple and easy.
You can take care of it
It named "Lynda.com - Android App Development with Java Essential Training"

Answer (score 0):

Here you can learn how to download eclipse and how to set it up.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Here you can learn you to code :D

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd also check out [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) alongside / instead of eclipse. It's beginning to become widely used in the industry and shouldn't be in preview too much longer :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up development environment
An easy way to set up:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

Then try http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html to have a feel how to program in android

Comment: I have already posted that links :)